# Locate and display data using listbox in vba

Tags: vba, excel

I have tried this code to locate specific data from excel using List Box in VBA, It populated a list of names from sheet3 range(E7), then everytime I click an item/name on it the program should located the name from sheet3 and display the data on that row into their corresponding textboxes in my userform.But this doesn't work pecisely.Thanks.

```
Private Sub ListBox1_Click()
Dim isRow As Long
    If Me.ListBox1.ListIndex > -1 Then
        isRow = Me.ListBox1.ListIndex + 1
    End If
    Me.Label1 = Cells(sRow, 5) 
    Me.txt_Mon_in.Text = Cells(sRow,6)

End Sub
```

Populating data from Sheet3.

```
Private Sub Userform_Initialize()
Dim vCol As Variant
Dim Lrow As Long
    Lrow = Sheets("Sheet3").UsedRange.Rows(Sheets("Sheet3").UsedRange.Rows.Count).Row
    vCol = Sheets("Sheet3").Range("E7:E" & Lrow).Value
    Me.ListBox1.List = vCol

End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Im not quite sure what you are doing but try the below code

```
Private Sub Userform_Initialize()
    Dim vCol As Variant
    Dim Lrow As Long
    Lrow = Sheets("Sheet3").UsedRange.Rows(Sheets("Sheet3").UsedRange.Rows.Count).Row
    vCol = Sheets("Sheet3").Range("E7:E" & Lrow).Value
    Me.ListBox1.List = vCol
End Sub


Private Sub ListBox1_Click()

    Dim selectedName As String
    Dim i As Long
    With ListBox1
        For i = 0 To .ListCount - 1
            If .Selected(i) Then
                selectedName = .List(i)
            End If
        Next i
    End With
    Dim c As Range
    For Each c In Sheets(3).Range("E7:E" & Sheets(3).Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
        If c = selectedName Then
            Label1 = Sheets("Sheet3").Cells(c.Row, 5)
            txt_Mon_in.Text = Sheets("Sheet3").Cells(c.Row, 6)
        End If
    Next c

End Sub
```

the `Listbox1_Click()` sub will iterate over the column E in sheet 3 and put the name in the `Label1` control and will put offset of (0,1) of the found cell into the `txt_Mon_in` contol.

Sheet3

[image]

Userform

[image]

Result

[image]

Comment: @mehow..This is exactly what I'm looking for.And as a beginner the explanation made me understand how this code works..Thank you!

Comment: @user2123999 you are welcome! for more information on [**how to build userforms see this**](http://vba4all.wordpress.com/category/vba-macros/two-column-listbox-userform-and-saving-results-to-spreadsheet/)

Comment: @mehow..Gonna have more time reading this.Sure this will give me further information :D